# When and why can `finally` be useful?

Tags: php, exception, try-catch-finally

PHP 5.5 has implemented `finally` to `try-catch`. My doubt is: when exactly `try-catch-finally` that might be more helpful than just I write below `try-catch`?

Example, difference between:

```
try { something(); }
catch(Exception $e) { other(); }
finally { another(); }
```

Instead of, just:

```
try { something(); }
catch(Exception $e) { other(); }
another();
```

Can send me some example that is common to this case?

**Notes**:

0. I talk about `try-catch-finally`, and not about `try-finally`, only;
1. There are some "features" cool, like you cancel current exception and throw a new-other-exception on finally (I don't tried, [I read here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php#112507)). I don't know if it is possible without `finally`;
2. Would not be more useful something like `notcatch`? So I can run a code if `try` goes without an exception. hehe

Comment: When something needs to happen regardless of an exception occurring.

Comment: The `finally` block will *always* be executed, whereas normal code after the `try-catch` may not be, in the case of returning from a method or similar.  This allows you to cleanup anything necessary, such as resource usage.

Comment: @Vulcan so if I do `try { return something(); } finally { other(); }`, `other()` will run? And if I do `finally { return other(); }`, what will be returned? It's possible?

Comment: @Vulcan About research, I do a lot, on Google and SO, but I found more related to Java, and I like to know over PHP. Java support thread, for instance, and finally seems that works even if thread go out, something like that. I don't know about Java, on really. :)

Comment: @DavidRodrigues The value returned in the `finally` block will be the actual value returned from the function.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/adf48d1bef3962571aae186ee8d804fecee7557e

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code within the `finally` block is always executed after leaving from either `try` or `catch` blocks. Of course you may continue writing code after the try-catch and it *will* be executed as well. But finally could be useful when you'd like to break out of code execution (such as returning from a function, breaking out of a loop etc.). You can find some examples on this page - https://www.php.net/exceptions, such as:

```
function example() {
  try {
     // open sql connection
     // Do regular work
     // Some error may happen here, raise exception
  }
  catch (Exception $e){
    return 0;
    // But still close sql connection
  }
  finally {
    //close the sql connection
    //this will be executed even if you return early in catch!
  }
}
```

But yes, you are right; `finally` is not very popular in everyday use. Certainly not as much as try-catch alone.

Comment: Your example covers the `try-finally` case, but the question specifies that only information about `try-catch-finally` is being asked.

Comment: Updated the example to make it more specific. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, positive! Just tested since you asked :D

Comment: Here, http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/42790c1e7806fb813fa81fad4690bbe78c7834d8

Comment: Pretty interesting, hm :) +1 for effort.

Answer (score 2):

You might not catch the exception you're throwing, but you still want to run your `finally` statement before throwing an error (eg. always close a log file or a DB connection before fatally failing because you didn't catch the exception):

```
<?php

$fHandle = fopen('log.txt', 'a');

try {
    echo 'Throwing exception..';
    fwrite($fHandle, 'Throwing exception..');

    throw new BadFunctionCallException();
} catch (RangeException $e) {
    // We only want to log RangeExceptions

    echo 'Threw a RangeException: ' . $e->getMessage();
    fwrite($fHandle, 'Threw a RangeException: ' . $e->getMessage());
} finally {
    // Always make sure that we close the file before throwing an exception, even if we don't catch it

    echo 'Reached the finally block';
    fwrite($fHandle, 'Reached the finally block');
    fclose($fHandle);
}
```

Which would output:

```
Throwing exception..Reached the finally block
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'BadFunctionCallException' in /tmp/execpad-dc59233db2b0/source-dc59233db2b0:6
Stack trace:
    #0 {main}
    thrown in /tmp/execpad-dc59233db2b0/source-dc59233db2b0 on line 6
```

[**DEMO** (without the `fopen` as `eval.in` doesn't support it)](https://eval.in/155813)