# PHP finally usage

Tags: php

Is there any point in using the `finally` block in PHP? If it always runs no matter what, could you just not have it in the block? For example, these will output the same:

1.

```
try {
    echo 'Hello';
    switch(false) {
        case 1==2:
            throw new Exception('error');
            break;
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
} finally {
    echo 'World';
}
```

2.

```
try {
    echo 'Hello';
    switch(false) {
        case 1==2:
            throw new Exception('error');
            break;
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
echo 'World';
```

They'll both echo:

```
Hello
error
World
```

This confuses me Lol

Comment: Good question, it's just been asked before. If anyone has a better answer, please post it there.

Comment: @WesleyMurch There's also another answer, which is that you might not nessesarily catch the exception, but you might still want to run the `finally` statement: [**DEMO**](https://eval.in/155810)

Comment: @h2ooooooo Ping me if you post an answer and I'll upvote it. You can post an answer that just covers what the other one did not, that is perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @WesleyMurch I've posted it as an answer on [the linked thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23813429/247893).

Comment: So ... What I kinda got from that, is that the `finally` clause is only useful if your code causes PHP to have a fatal error?